# Read data from tt_address and render a table. Table remains empty

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

i have a test enviroment with the intro-package, ods_osm and tt_address installed. on one page i want to show a table with marker data from tt_address (which is also used in the map). I am still struggling with typoscript, but this is what i have got so far:

Page ext Template:

```
lib.markerTable = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.markerTable {
    templateName = MarkerDetailsTemplate
    templateRootPaths {
        10 = fileadmin/user_upload/
    }
    variables {       
        markerData.select {
            pidInList = 85
            selectFields = uid, name, address, www
        }
    }
}
```

My fluidtemplate:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Website</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <f:for each="{markerData}" as="marker">
            <tr>
                <td>{marker.name}</td>
                <td>{marker.address}</td>
                <td><a href="{marker.www}" target="_blank">{marker.www}</a></td>
            </tr>
        </f:for>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To render the table i include this line into the Default.html:

```
<div class="marker-table-section">
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.markerTable" />
</div>
```

But in the Frontend i only see the table headers. Where i am going wrong?

Thanks!

Edit(TSOB entry):

```
[markerTable] = FLUIDTEMPLATE

    [templateName] = MarkerDetailsTemplate

[templateRootPaths]
[variables]

[markerData]

[select]

    [pidInList] = 85
    [selectFields] = uid, name, address, www
```

Comment: what is the definition of `lib.markerTable.variables.markerData`? find the full configuration in the `TSOB` (TypoScriptObjectBrowser)

Comment: I edited the question to insert the TSOB you asked for. I hope thats the correct info^^

Comment: If that is all the configuration `markerData` can not be evaluated in TypoScript and therefore can not have any data in FLUID. You miss a complete definition of a TypoScript object. There must be something like `markerData = CONTENT`. I asked for the TSOB because your code looks like an enhancement or overwrite of some existing code. maybe you missed to include some static template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DatabaseQueryProcessor` like this:

```
lib.markerTable = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.markerTable {
  templateName = MarkerDetailsTemplate
  templateRootPaths {
    10 = fileadmin/user_upload/
  }
  dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
  dataProcessing.10 {
    table = tt_address
    pidInList = 85
    selectFields = tt_address.*
  }
}
```

Then you can access the fields like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Website</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <f:for each="{records}" as="record">
    <tr>
      <td>{record.data.name}</td>
      <td>{record.data.address}</td>
      <td><a href="{record.data.www}" target="_blank">{record.data.www}</a></td>
    </tr>
  </f:for>
  </tbody>
</table>
```